# how to detect multiple clicks on a cell of same row and prevent it in jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1
    </th>
    <th>Heading 2
    </th>
    <th>Heading 3
    </th>
    <th>Heading 4
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

When I click a particular cell I get its cell value.

```
  $('td').click(function () {

    var col_index = $(this).text();

    console.log("Text: " + col_index);
});
```

What I want is, when I click the **different cell** of **same row** I want to alert a message that 'You cannot click another value once clicked' or something like that.

For example, if you look in to the table, for the first time I click Value 1, but then if I go click Value 2 it should prevent me to do click.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store a map of clicked cells in a specific row and if something has been already clicked then display an alert:

```js
var td_map = {};

$('td').click(function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $td = $this.parent();
    var col_index = $(this).text();
    
    if (td_map[$td.index()] === undefined || td_map[$td.index()] === col_index) {
      td_map[$td.index()] = col_index;
      console.log("Text: " + col_index);
    } else {
      alert('You cannot select two cells in one row');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1
    </th>
    <th>Heading 2
    </th>
    <th>Heading 3
    </th>
    <th>Heading 4
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! :)